# Phrase for suddenly getting to your feet

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase to express that type of getting to your feet, when you were on your knees and you try to dash into a run, but it’s like your legs are tripping on each other. Imagine a drunk marathon runner, unable to get up, but trying to run anyway.

Comment: ***stagger to your feet**: The man staggered to his feet and ran away.*  Macmillan Dictionary http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/stagger_1

Comment: "scramble to your feet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be many verb collocations with "to one's feet" that would work. Consider these options:

1. **to stumble to your feet**:

> to stumble: to proceed unsteadily or falteringly; flounder. ([AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=stumble))
>
> Example: *With a curse, Phillip stumbled to his feet.* ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=qynBAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA339&lpg=PA339&dq=%22stumbled%20to%20his%20feet%22&source=bl&ots=z16X7lpP2w&sig=AbQS7y380N_zLHAiIY1DTWpg3Jc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAmoVChMIgueqxOzvyAIVhbQPCh3RrAQ6#v=onepage&q&f=false))

2. **to hobble to your feet** (especially if your legs hurt or are injured):

> to hobble: to walk or move along haltingly or with difficulty ([AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hobble))
>
> Example: *Logan hobbled to his feet as Tom set his hand under his arm to help him up.* ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=YqWoBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT219&lpg=PT219&dq=%22Logan%20hobbled%20to%20his%20feet%20as%20Tom%20set%20his%20hand%20under%20his%20arm%20to%20help%20him%20up.%22&source=bl&ots=1Ya4Ghisk6&sig=_QBDI-xiiZthlq2OpGrQJ8IVHU0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAGoVChMIj9ixrO3vyAIVwx0PCh1W6QX2#v=onepage&q&f=false))

3. **to stagger to your feet** (as suggested by chasly form UK in comments), or **to totter to your feet**:

> to stagger: to move or stand unsteadily, as if under a great weight; totter ([AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=stagger))
>
> Example: *Riker staggered to his feet and buckled the deadly disruptor around his own hips, then shuffled back to the master controls.* ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=-QKf9aykM6IC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=staggered%20to%20his%20feet&source=bl&ots=lAWVICrAf9&sig=IaDKj2bgeE43qa79TgGRxUyezUo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE4Q6AEwCGoVChMIzaaD1O3vyAIVR2EOCh1hkQWl#v=onepage&q&f=false))